# Are there any practical uses of onomatopoeia in contemporary English?

Tags: vocabulary

Do we have any practical uses of onomatopoeia in contemporary English? I can not claim to have read many materials, but I have to confess I have rarely seen it used a lot.

Comment: How did you get to this site without *clicking*?

Comment: @RegDwight: *Poof!* Mind = blown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each onomatopoeic word is its own entity.  Asking whether there are any practical uses for onomatopoeia is similar to asking whether there are any practical uses for words ending in *f*.  You have to evaluate each word on a case-by-case basis.

Here is a list of some onomatopoeic words ([from here](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/examples-of-onomatopoeia.html)):

> Buzz, Beep, Whirr, Click, Clack, Clunk, Clatter, Clink, Achoo, Ahem, Fizz, Bah, Bump, Bam, Bang, Bash, Puff, Bawl, Boing, Bong, Bonk, Boo, Varoom, vroom, Bubble, Whoosh, Slurp, Wham, Biff, Pow, Snore, Swish, Swoosh, Blare, Blurt, Boing, Boink, Boom, Slurch, Clank, Clatter, Click, Ring, Ting, Honk, Jingle, Toot, Hum, Thud, Tick-tock, Cluck, Poof, Crackle, Ding, Hiccup, Crunch, Eek, Flick, Ping, Plop, Zap, Zing, Zip, Zoom

*Buzz*, *beep*, *honk*, *plop* (and so on) are perfectly normal, commonly-used English words. These words can be any type of lexical category, and can be just as useful as any other type of word.

Comment: The repeated words in that list bother me, but that's not your fault. Good answer.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Got rid of those I was able to see :)

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of onomatopoeia going on in English all the time.

A few common words that are largely onomatopoetic:

sigh whack whoosh plink ping-pong plop flop whisk blab murmur susurrus pop click honk bark yap

Comment: gah, badly out-listed by Kosmonaut.  :-p

Comment: Haha, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can say that *cuckoo* is an onomatopoeic word, or that is an onomatopoeia.

Apart from using *onomatopoeia* to mean that a word is formed from the sound it describes, or to refer to the use of such words for rhetorical effect, I don't think you usually use that word.

**<sub>[Reference: the New Oxford American Dictionary.]</sub>**